# Checking multiple format of dates in several html page

Tags: python-3.x, regex

i need to parse date from html codes. The dates can be in different formats.

**Issue**

How to check for multiple patterns of date in the following code.

**Different formats needed to check are**

```
[ADFJMNOS]\w* [\d]{1,2}. [\d]{4}  
[\d]{1,2} [ADFJMNOS]\w*, [\d]{4}
[\d]{4}, [ADFJMNOS]\w* [\d]{1,2}
[ADFJMNOS]\w* [\d]{1,2} - [\d]{1,2}, [\d]{4}
```

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}

url_list = ['https://www.grsymphony.org/american-in-paris','https://www.toledosymphony.com/events/2021/06/04/promedica-masterworks/beethoven-s-pastoral/',
           'https://www.toledosymphony.com/events/2021/09/24/promedica-masterworks/musical-portraits/',
           'https://www.staatsoper.de/stueckinfo/les-troyens-1/2022-05-09-17-00.html?tx_sfstaatsoper_pi1%5BfromSpielplan%5D=1&tx_sfstaatsoper_pi1%5BpageId%5D=528&cHash=3ce5142af1140c90522372caa4330efb',
           'https://www.hso.org/concerts/an-innocent-man-the-music-of-billy-joel/',
           'https://www.hso.org/concerts/beethoven-triple-concerto/','https://www.seattlesymphony.org/en/concerttickets/calendar/2021-2022/21bar3',]

# keeping it simple: download from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads (match version of Chrome installed)
# put the extracted file in same folder as the script.  Firefox driver is available if you search for it
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/ubuntu/selenium_drivers/chromedriver')

for URL in url_list:
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    data = driver.page_source
    cleantext = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml").text
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    x = re.sub(cleanr, '', cleantext)
    all_dates = re.findall(r"[ADFJMNOS]\w* [\d]{1,2}, [\d]{4}", x) 
    print(URL)
    for s in all_dates:
        print(s)
```

**Present output** some sites are evading due to different format of dates :(

```
https://www.grsymphony.org/american-in-paris
January 07, 2022
January 08, 2022
https://www.toledosymphony.com/events/2021/06/04/promedica-masterworks/beethoven-s-pastoral/
June 4, 2021
June 5, 2021
https://www.toledosymphony.com/events/2021/09/24/promedica-masterworks/musical-portraits/
https://www.staatsoper.de/stueckinfo/les-troyens-1/2022-05-09-17-00.html?tx_sfstaatsoper_pi1%5BfromSpielplan%5D=1&tx_sfstaatsoper_pi1%5BpageId%5D=528&cHash=3ce5142af1140c90522372caa4330efb
https://www.hso.org/concerts/an-innocent-man-the-music-of-billy-joel/
March 19, 2022
https://www.hso.org/concerts/beethoven-triple-concerto/
November 12, 2021
https://www.seattlesymphony.org/en/concerttickets/calendar/2021-2022/21bar3
May 20, 2022
May 21, 2022
```

Comment: Note: You will never know if `01-02-2021` is the `January 2nd` (`dd-mm`), or `February 1th` (`mm-dd`).

Comment: You should narrow down the problem to only ask about what you have problems with. This will make the question shorter and more likely to get a fast answer.

Comment: Will this work [ADFJMNOS]\w* [\d]{1,2} - [\d]{1,2}, [\d]{4} for September 24 - 25, 2021 ?

Comment: REGEX101 is a great site to test your regular expressions, see: https://regex101.com/r/jigQHK/1

Comment: @Luuk Thankyou for the quick response. How can i find dates which matches a group of pattern.

Comment: got the output...

Comment: Thank you all for the valuable suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}

url_list = ['https://www.grsymphony.org/american-in-paris','https://www.toledosymphony.com/events/2021/06/04/promedica-masterworks/beethoven-s-pastoral/',
           'https://www.toledosymphony.com/events/2021/09/24/promedica-masterworks/musical-portraits/',
           'https://www.staatsoper.de/stueckinfo/les-troyens-1/2022-05-09-17-00.html?tx_sfstaatsoper_pi1%5BfromSpielplan%5D=1&tx_sfstaatsoper_pi1%5BpageId%5D=528&cHash=3ce5142af1140c90522372caa4330efb',
           'https://www.hso.org/concerts/an-innocent-man-the-music-of-billy-joel/',
           'https://www.hso.org/concerts/beethoven-triple-concerto/','https://www.seattlesymphony.org/en/concerttickets/calendar/2021-2022/21bar3',]
# keeping it simple: download from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads (match version of Chrome installed)
# put the extracted file in same folder as the script.  Firefox driver is available if you search for it
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/ubuntu/selenium_drivers/chromedriver')
format_list = ["[\d]{1,2}. [ADFJMNOS]\w* [\d]{4}","[ADFJMNOS]\w* [\d]{1,2}, [\d]{4}","[\d]{1,2} [ADFJMNOS]\w*, [\d]{4}","[\d]{4}, [ADFJMNOS]\w* [\d]{1,2}","[ADFJMNOS]\w* [\d]{1,2} - [\d]{1,2}, [\d]{4}"]
for URL in url_list:
    date = []
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.implicitly_wait(4)
    data = driver.page_source
    cleantext = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml").text
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    x = re.sub(cleanr, '', cleantext)
    print(URL)
    for pattern in format_list:
        all_dates = re.findall(pattern, x)
        if all_dates == []:
            continue
        else:
            date.append(all_dates)
    for s in date:
        print(s)
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.